# flutter The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned

Tags: list, flutter, class, parameters, arguments

Hey guys I ran into a problem that I don't know how to resolve.

I have a Character class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Character {
  final String name;
  final String imagePath;
  final String description;
  final List<Color> colors;

  Character({
    required this.name,
    required this.imagePath,
    required this.description,
    required this.colors,
  });
}

List characters = [
  Character(
      name: 'Kevin',
      imagePath: 'assets/images/Kevin_minions.png',
      description:
          'Sir Kevin KBE (formerly known as Kevin) is one of the Minions and the protagonist in the film Minions. Kevin is a tall, two-eyed minion with sprout cut hair and is usually seen wearing his golf apparel. Kevin loves to make fun of and tease people or Minions, shown when he made fun of Jerry and teases him for being a coward. He loves playing golf and cricket. In the film Minions he is the leader of the trio in search of a new master. He truly cares about the well-being of the Minion tribe (which is dependent on them having a proper master).',
      colors: [Colors.orange.shade200, Colors.deepOrange.shade400]),
  Character(
      name: "Agnes",
      imagePath: "assets/images/Agnes_gru.png",
      description:
          "Agnes Gru it is one of Gru and Lucy's three adopted daughters, alongside her sisters Margo and Edith. She is the youngest child of the three sisters. She greatly adores unicorns, as shown on various occasions. Agnes is a little girl with dark brown eyes. Her long black hair is tied in an upwards ponytail with a red scrunchie. Most of the time, Agnes wears blue overalls over a yellow and brown striped t-shirt, and white sneakers with yellow socks. She also wears a white ballet outfit like Edith and Margo (at the ballet recital). For pajamas, Agnes wears a long blue nightshirt covered with teddy bears and polar bear slippers; her hair stays the same. On her birthday, Agnes is wearing a dress that resembles a princess riding a unicorn. The colors are similar to her regular outfit. She also wears a blue princess hat on her head.",
      colors: [Colors.pink.shade200, Colors.redAccent.shade400]),
];
```

Also a Character info or detail page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mimir_minions/models/character.dart';
import 'package:mimir_minions/styleguide.dart';

class CharacterDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Character character;

  const CharacterDetailPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.character,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CharacterDetailPageState createState() => _CharacterDetailPageState();
}

class _CharacterDetailPageState extends State<CharacterDetailPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          Hero(
            tag: "background_${widget.character.name}",
            child: DecoratedBox(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(35),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(35),
                ),
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: widget.character.colors,
                  begin: Alignment.topRight,
                  end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 56.0, 0, 0),
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.close,
                    ),
                    iconSize: 48,
                    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  child: Hero(
                    tag: "image_${widget.character.name}",
                    child: Image.asset(
                      widget.character.imagePath,
                      height: screenHeight * 0.45,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0, vertical: 8),
                  child: Hero(
                      tag: "name_${widget.character.name}",
                      child: Material(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          child: Container(
                              child: Text(widget.character.name,
                                  style: AppTheme.heading)))),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 0, 32.0, 24.0),
                  child: Text(widget.character.description,
                      style: AppTheme.subHeading),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and a character widget page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mimir_minions/models/character.dart';
import 'package:mimir_minions/pages/character_detail_page.dart';
import 'package:mimir_minions/styleguide.dart';

class CharacterWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const CharacterWidget({Key? key, required this.character}) : super(key: key);

  final Character character;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          PageRouteBuilder(
            transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 350),
            pageBuilder: (context, _, __) => CharacterDetailPage(
              character: characters,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Hero(
              tag: "background_${characters[0].name}",
              child: ClipPath(
                clipper: CharacterCardBackgroundClipper(),
                child: Container(
                  height: screenHeight * 0.6,
                  width: screenWidth * 0.9,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: characters[0].colors,
                      begin: Alignment.topRight,
                      end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment(0, -0.6),
            child: Hero(
              tag: "image_${characters[0].name}",
              child: Image.asset(
                characters[0].imagePath,
                height: screenHeight * 0.55,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 32, right: 8, bottom: 16),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Hero(
                    tag: "name_${characters[0].name}",
                    child: Material(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: Container(
                            child: Text(characters[0].name,
                                style: AppTheme.heading)))),
                Text('Tap to read more', style: AppTheme.subHeading),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CharacterCardBackgroundClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path clippedPath = Path();
    double curveDistance = 40;

    clippedPath.moveTo(0, size.height * 0.4);
    clippedPath.lineTo(0, size.height - curveDistance);
    clippedPath.quadraticBezierTo(
        1, size.height - 1, 0 + curveDistance, size.height);
    clippedPath.lineTo(size.width - curveDistance, size.height);
    clippedPath.quadraticBezierTo(size.width + 1, size.height - 1, size.width,
        size.height - curveDistance);
    clippedPath.lineTo(size.width, 0 + curveDistance);
    clippedPath.quadraticBezierTo(size.width - 1, 0,
        size.width - curveDistance - 5, 0 + curveDistance / 3);
    clippedPath.lineTo(curveDistance, size.height * 0.29);
    clippedPath.quadraticBezierTo(
        1, (size.height * 0.30) + 10, 0, size.height * 0.4);
    return clippedPath;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

When I use the character as a list like `character[0].name` I have no problem. However, when I want to change it to the `character` so I have several character widgets on my first page it gives me an error that says

> The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter
> type 'Character'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)

[This is the link to my repo on Github](https://github.com/MimirCode/mimir_minions.git)

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear you are trying to use a List when Dart is expecting a single instance of Character.

I think what you are trying to achieve is a master/detail view.
You should have one CharacterList widget

```dart
class CharacterList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Character> characters;

  const CharacterList({Key? key, required this.characters}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: characters.length, itemBuilder: (context, index) => CharacterWidget(character: characters[index])),
    );
  }
}
```

This `ListView` will be your master view and on any of the `CharacterWidget` they should take you to the detail view, but you should start using the `character` attribute instead of the `characters` list in your `CharacterWidget`

```
 return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          PageRouteBuilder(
            transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 350),
            pageBuilder: (context, _, __) => CharacterDetailPage(
              character: character,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Hero(
              tag: "background_${character.name}",// instead of  "background_${characters[0].name}"
              child: ClipPath(
```

Comment: No problem, hope it solved your issue. If that was the case, mark the answer as accepted or post your own and mark it as accepted if it drifted too apart from mine, in order for other user to see it as `answered` .

Comment: Thank you so much, This actually didn't work for me and I realized that I should have used `character` instead of `characters`